# HTML Table with one big area and two small ones

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to create the table shown in the link - in HTML but I have no idea how to do the two small compartments on the right.

Anyone got any ideas?

[image: http://gyazo.com/b8e2b3cd5d122c6bf6256152284c0453]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables should be used only for real tables.
For this purpose(i guess its styling page) the best is usage of div elements.

```
<div style="float:left;">left div</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <div>right top</div>
    <div>right bottom</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Agreed – but the code is for an email footer and I have been warned not to do it this way as a number of email providers will not display it correctly.

Comment: Wrap this code with another div, set elements exact width and height. do not forget to clear floating. You will be fine, I am using floating in html emails and everything is alright.